# moving data to $.ajax's out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I want to move "data" variable to out of success function for other operation.

```
$("a[class=note]").click(function( evt ){
                    var note = $(this).attr("value");
                    var preid = $(this).attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'style/ajax.php',
                        data: 'do=note&value=' + note + '&preid=' + preid,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

For example php have `Global` pharase..

Comment: You can add it to `window` (e.g., `window.myData = data;`) but are you sure this is the way to go?

Comment: just use a global variable, you set within `success`

Comment: If you want it global, then create a global variable and assign it. `globalData = data`. I wouldn't recommend global variables though.

Comment: Change the selector from `$("a[class=note]")` ==> `$("a.note")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

global var(which is the worse solution, but this is what you asked for):

```
$("a.note").click(function( evt ){
                var note = $(this).attr("value");
                var preid = $(this).attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'style/ajax.php',
                    data: 'do=note&value=' + note + '&preid=' + preid,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        window.data = data;
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

global variable are dangerous, Maybe variable outside the success scope is enough?
Var outside the `success` callback:

```
$("a.note").click(function( evt ){
                var note = $(this).attr("value");
                var preid = $(this).attr("id");
                var dataFromServer = null;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'style/ajax.php',
                    data: 'do=note&value=' + note + '&preid=' + preid,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        dataFromServer = data;
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Last option is to have a hidden input that will store the data;

```
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('#hiddenFieldId').val(data);
                        alert(data);
                    }
```

Things to notice:

1. I changed your selector from `a[class=note]` to `a.note` which is better.
2. `success` is a **callback** which means it will not be fired until the response reach the client, until then your global\outside var\hidden input value will be null. if you don't want the `ajax` to be `asynchronous` you can define it in the options like this:

---

```
  $.ajax({
    async: false, //  <---
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'style/ajax.php',
    data: 'do=note&value=' + note + '&preid=' + preid,
    success: function(data)
    {
        dataFromServer = data;
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Joseph. `success` is a `callback function` it will be fired only when the response will get to the client. so your's alert is fired before the `dataFromServer` assignment. You can add `async:false` if you want to wait until the `success` is fired.

Comment: OK. problem is the timeOut is it not?

Comment: @Joseph. The problem is that `Ajax` is asynchronous, so the request-response still didn't finished but the rest of your Javascript continue to execute.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a[class=note]").click(function( evt ){
                    var note = $(this).attr("value");
                    var preid = $(this).attr("id");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'style/ajax.php',
                        data: 'do=note&value=' + note + '&preid=' + preid,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            window.data = data;
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Of course you can't use it until the callback fires.

Answer (score 2):

Define `var data = null;` above all your code, that would be global variable. After that, rename argument for process function and in function body `window.data = response;`.

**EDIT**

You can define function to trigger data changes, for example:

```
var data = null;

function setGlobal(v) {
    window.data = v;
    alert(window.data);
}

$("a[class=note]").click(function( evt ){
    var note = $(this).attr("value");
    var preid = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'style/ajax.php',
        data: 'do=note&value=' + note + '&preid=' + preid,
        success: function(data){
            setGlobal(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Try it...

Comment: Are you sure you're calling right URL? What's in the console? If you got `null` alerting data from response, that's the request problem, not variable.

Comment: Why to declare `var data = null`?

Comment: Cause it's a code grammar... If you want to use GLOBAL var, you need to see all of the global vars are used. Otherwise there will be overloading in using varibales.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but you're wrong. there will be no overloading but **overriding**.

Comment: OR redeclaring, or whatever - it's a bad manners. Just forgotten right translation...

Comment: I feel rude "picking" on you, but defining `var data = null` won't help, this why **global vars are deprecated...**

Comment: I'd like to prove you my point of view. For example you have a lot of global variables, that you MUST use, because some of your coworkers use it. If they define that vars wherever they want to how you would know that var that you want to use under the root of the script won't give a bug? In other case, if you define all global variables in a one single place, by `var data = null;` everyone could see it, and that prevents you from making a @bug@. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: And please, give me a prove link, why you supposed that global vars in javascript is deprecated?